# Different transfer rate on 1000BASE-T Network

Tags: networking, ethernet, troubleshooting, gigabit-ethernet

I have a really strange behavior that I do not understand.

Equipment used:

```
Laptop 1000BASE-T NIC
Stationary Workstation 1000BASE-T NIC
Raspberry Pi 4b 1000BASE-T NIC
Cisco Switch 1000BASE-T
```

Netperf and iPerf3 for testing network performance.

**What is happening:**

SETUP 1:

[image: System Overview]

I swapped the cables and get completely different connection.

SETUP 2:

[image: System overview 2]

SETUP 3:

[image: System overview 3]

As you can see the transfer rate depends on which HW I am using. All nodes are 1000BASE-T. It seems like the negotiation uses different standards.

**Questions:**

Why/How does the RPi4 get NO CARRIER on PORT one(1) when Laptop get 1000MBps and Stationary get 100Mbps

Why is the transfer rate 940Mbps Between Laptop and Stationary workstation, when the Stationary workstation identifies the link as 100Mbps and not 1000Mbps.

WHAT I EXCEPT: 100Mbps link due to the reduced number of Diff-pairs on Port one(1). Not 940Mbps on transfer rate through the faulty ethernet port. More like 94Mbps.

Comment: The laptop and stationary workstation might support auto MDI-X negotiation of the pairs in the cable. It could mean that in one direction gigabit is possible, and that direction could potentially be being negotiated as required on the fly. The Pi may not support MDI-X and if it is the pairs which are used for 100Mbps that are damaged it may simply see no connection on that pair and simply assume that there is no cable. Ethernet autonegotiation expects a pulse to be seen on the wire and it may be that the laptop checks *all* pairs while the Pi only checks the "main" pairs used for 100baseTX.

Comment: I think I am being silly here. On port 2 it is always running at 1Gbps regardless of how it is wired up. The problems on port 1 indicate a hardware problem on that port on the switch. The fact that it sometimes works or the speed differs just points you to the problem... your port 1 switch is faulty.